# Why are there three kinds of results in my multithreading program?

Tags: java, thread-safety

```
class Threadtest6 implements Runnable {
    int i = 1;
    static int sum = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (; i < 10; i++) {
            //There are three cases where the main function outputs a different result


            //1.The result is 45  The next one lines are the code
            // sum = sum + i;

            //2.The result is 55  The next two lines are the code
            //System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "---" + i);
            //sum = sum + i;

            //3.The result is 46 The next two lines are the code
            //sum = sum + i;
            //System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "---" + i);

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Threadtest6 t1 = new Threadtest6();
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(t1);
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(t1);
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        //Prevents the main thread from completing first
        Thread.sleep(500);
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

In this code, there are three outcomes. I think I have used sleep anyway, and I have tested it about 5 times for each case. Why does such a situation occur?

Comment: What three outcomes? What are you seeing? What are you expecting? Why are you expecting it? What is your question?

Comment: You can start here: [What is a race condition?](//stackoverflow.com/q/34510)

Comment: Why do these results occur in the absence of the synchronized keyword?Shouldn't the results be random within a range?

Answer (score 0):

The result of repeated executions seems to be fixed. In fact, because the data is not enough, if the range of i is expanded, for example, i<10 is changed to i<10000, the result of multiple executions will not be the same. As for why the result of i<10 is related to the location of 'sum = sum + i;', I think this should be the result of multi-threaded competition.